# Conditional member function execution

Tags: c++

Suppose you have a class `Foo` with a function `Foo::bar()`. 
Surrounding this function is a `Monitor<Foo>` class, which wrapps around `Foo` and forwards any function call by overloading `operator->`.

Further, the Monitor class has a boolean flag `execute`. If `execute` is true, all function calls
of Foo should be executed normally, but if `execute` is set to false, execution should be skipped.

The following snippet shows how this could look like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
  void bar() {std::cout << "Foo::bar()";}
};

template<typename T> class Monitor<T> {
  T& ref;
  bool exec;
public:
  Monitor(T& obj) : ref(obj), exec(true) {}
  T* operator->() {/* if exec */ return &ref;}
  void setExec(bool e) {exec = e;}
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  Monitor<Foo> monitor(foo);

  monitor->bar(); // call Foo::bar();
  monitor.setExec(false);
  monitor->bar(); // do nothing
}
```

Is this possible to implement? The obvious solution is to have a Base class `IFoo`, and
a Mock implementation `MockFoo` doing nothing, and then return a pointer to a `MockFoo` object
when `operator->` is called. This makes the whole thing rather inflexible however, as you have to 
provide a Mock object for any class you want to monitor.

So, is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Any critique on how to improve my question or clarify?

Comment: I think if you want to be able to call any member function of the monitored class as `monitor->somefunc`, there is no other way than a mock class. You are returning a `T*` from the `->` operator, so, whatever it is, it has to provide `somefunc`, otherwise it won't even compile. If you only want to call a *specific* method of the monitored class(es), you could return a function object calling that method (or an empty dummy, if the flag is false) instead of the class itself (probably not using the `->` operator, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you know which function you are going to call, you could do something like the following. This even allows for specification of a default return value of the function in the case `exec==false`. I am sure I didn't consider all the possible traps of reference return arguments, const member functions, etc. But I am sure you can adapt it if you want to use it.

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    double callX(const int& x){ return x/100.;};
};

struct Y {
    int callY(const std::string& y){ return y.length();};
};

template<typename F> class Monitor;

template<typename T, typename Ret, typename ...Args>
class Monitor<Ret(T::*)(Args...)> {
    T& ref;
    Ret(T::*func)(Args...);
    Ret defaultRet;
    bool exec;
public:
    Monitor(T& ref, Ret(T::*func)(Args...), Ret defaultRet = Ret())
        : ref(ref),
          func(func),
          defaultRet(defaultRet),
          exec(true){};
    void setExec(bool e) {exec = e;};
    Ret call(Args&&... args) {
        if(exec)
            return (ref.*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        else
            return defaultRet;
    };

};

template<typename T, typename Ret, typename ...Args>
auto makeMonitor(T& x, Ret(T::*f)(Args...), Ret r = Ret()) {
    return Monitor<Ret(T::*)(Args...)>(x,f,r);
}


int main() {
    X x;
    Y y;
    auto xmon = makeMonitor(x, &X::callX);
    auto ymon = makeMonitor(y, &Y::callY);
    auto ymon_def = makeMonitor(y, &Y::callY, 123);
    std::cout << "callX(3)=" << xmon.call(3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "callY(\"hello\")=" << ymon.call("hello") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[default return] callY(\"hello\")=" << ymon_def.call("hello") << std::endl;
    xmon.setExec(false);
    ymon.setExec(false);
    ymon_def.setExec(false);
    std::cout << "After setExec(false):" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "callX(3)=" << xmon.call(3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "callY(\"hello\")=" << ymon.call("hello") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[default return] callY(\"hello\")=" << ymon_def.call("hello") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
callX(3)=0.03
callY("hello")=5
[default return] callY("hello")=5
After setExec(false):
callX(3)=0
callY("hello")=0
[default return] callY("hello")=123
```

Working example is [here](http://ideone.com/hMhNPb).

The "obvious" solution you mentioned can be streamlined a little, so you only have to define one additional (mock) class and no additional base classes. If you don't mind the slight performance loss due to virtual member functions, you can go about it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MockX;

struct X {
    typedef MockX mock;
    virtual double doX(int x){ return x/100.;};
};

struct MockX : X {
    virtual double doX(int x){ return 0.;};
};

struct MockY;

struct Y {
    typedef MockY mock;
    virtual int doY(std::string y){ return y.length();};
};

struct MockY : Y {
    virtual int doY(std::string y){ return 123;};
};


template <typename T>
struct Monitor {
    T& ref;
    static typename T::mock dummy;
    bool exec;
    Monitor(T& ref) : ref(ref), exec(true){};
    void setExec(bool e){exec = e;};
    T* operator->(){
        if(exec)
            return &ref;
        else
            return &dummy;
    };
};

template<typename T>
typename T::mock Monitor<T>::dummy{};

int main() {
    X x;
    Y y;
    auto xmon = Monitor<X>(x);
    auto ymon = Monitor<Y>(y);
    std::cout << "doX(3)=" << xmon->doX(3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "doY(\"hello\")=" << ymon->doY("hello") << std::endl;
    xmon.setExec(false);
    ymon.setExec(false);
    std::cout << "After setExec(false):" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "doX(3)=" << xmon->doX(3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "doY(\"hello\")=" << ymon->doY("hello") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I made the `dummy` mock object `static`, so there will only be one copy for each type you're monitoring. Everything you need is a typedef in the real class specifying your mock class, and the mock class inheriting from the real class and overriding the (virtual) methods you want to disable when `exec==false`. You have to be aware though that even the methods you don't override will be called on the `dummy` object when `exec==false`, so they might not behave as expected.

However, this could also be an advantage: If you write `X` and `Y` in such a way that a default-constructed object (or one constructed with a special flag specified in the constructor) behaves like a mock class, you don't even need a mock-class (just construct `dummy` that way). But then you could almost build that "disabling" functionality into `X` itself and you don't need the monitor... ;-)

Comment: Your idea shows me how difficult it is what I want (especially if you have to deal with return types...). My goal would have been to keep the interface transparent, so there is no difference in calling a `pX->callX()` or `monitorX->callX()`.

Comment: That's really not possible, I think (because you cannot programmatically change a class). Probably your "obvious solution" is the best one then... I will try to think of ways to make that approach more convenient.

Comment: In the end I used the Mock approach. As I already have a class structure with base class, it is not too much of a change. Pity there is no other way though...